# I need help debugging my transaction.split method

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

The goal of this function is to calculate the buying and selling of stocks. For some reason the transaction.split method is returning an error. The error is saying the method needs 3 arguments, which I have. Any help in this is great appreciated!

```
from collections import deque

def calculate_gain(stock_transactions):
    gain = 0
    shares_bought = deque()

    for transaction in stock_transactions:
        action, num_shares, share_price = transaction.split()
        num_shares = int(num_shares)
        share_price = int(share_price)

        if action == 'buy':
            shares_bought.append((num_shares, share_price))
        else:
            shares_sold = num_shares

    while shares_sold > 0:
        shares = shares_bought.popleft()
        if shares[0] > shares_sold:
            gain += shares_sold * (share_price - shares[1])
            shares[0] -= shares_sold
            shares_bought.appendleft(shares)
            shares_sold = 0
        else:
            gain += shares[0] * (share_price - shares[1])
            shares_sold -= shares[0]

    return gain

    stock_transactions = [
    "buy 100 shares at 20 each",
    "buy 20 shares at 24 each",
    "buy 200 shares at 36 each",
    "sell 150 shares at 30 each"
    ]

    total_gain = calculate_gain(stock_transactions)
    print(f"The total capital gain is ${total_gain}")
```

I tried changing the names of the arguments, the spacing, and the indentation. It is still not splitting correctly.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBUfF.png)

Comment: Please post the exact error message and traceback. Also show the value of `stock_transactions`.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any empty strings in `stock_transactions`.

Comment: "The error is saying the method needs 3 arguments, which I have" why would you give us just a vague description of the error message? The python runtime goes to great lengths to provide an informative error message and a stack trace **precisely because** it helps debugging. Why would you just *omit* that?

Comment: Error message:ERROR!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 37, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 8, in calculate_gain
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: Your `transaction`s don't consist of 3 items. They seem to be strings that split into 6 substrings. You need to parse those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you are trying to unpack the result of splitting strings like `"buy 20 shares at 24 each"` into just 3 variables. That split has 6 items, hence the `too many values to unpack (expected 3)` error message. To fix it, just split the transaction and then extract the fields that you care about:

```
transaction = transaction.split()
action = transaction[0]
num_shares = int(transaction[1])
share_price = int(transaction[4])
```

If you make that change then your code almost works, but you are trying to mutate a tuple in the line `shares[0] -= shares_sold`. To fix this, redefine `shares_bought` to be a deque of lists rather than a deque of tuples:

```
shares_bought.append([num_shares, share_price])
```